# inspite of mentioning allowed_client_ids in api declaration all web clients are able to access api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

```
import endpoints

from protorpc import messages #for encapsulating data for sending

from protorpc import message_types

WEB_CLIENT_ID = '644515464936-552tgvthbmnhopg6qe71e99rrfbjatj7.apps.googleusercontent.com'

class HelloMessage(messages.Message):

    msg = messages.StringField(1)

@endpoints.api(name='myapiversion1',

               version='v1',
               allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID],
               audiences=[WEB_CLIENT_ID],
               scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
               auth_level=AUTH_LEVEL_REQUIRED,
               hostname='maulikversion1.appspot.com')
```

api url : https://maulikversion1.appspot.com/_ah/api/maulikversion1/v1/say_hello

I tried accesing it from www.hurl.it a web tool for testing rest api, and it was able to access the api.

Q1
what error it should give instead of allowing to access my custom api?
unfortunately it is allowing any web client to access api.

Q2.
AUTH_LEVEL_REQUIRED is not defined - internal server error

Answer (score 0):

It is now restricting other web clients to access the api

I guess the client id generation took time to reflect at production-environment